# Javascript Regexp validation not quite working

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to use RegExp validation for a number that can have up to 5 numbers followed up one option decimal place. Like 48293 or 23.4 are good. 99.99 or 453543 are not. I wrote the following function:

```
function validateLoad(load_value) {
 var matchValue = new RegExp('[0-9]{1,5}(\.[0-9]{1})?')
 return matchValue.test(load_value)
}
```

However, this seems to return true for all numerical values, can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: up to means from 0, then you should change to `[0-9]{0,5}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) to make sure the entire string (and not just a substring) is matched by the regex. Also, don't forget to double the backslashes if you construct the regex from a string (and drop the `{1}`, it's a no-op):

```
var matchValue = new RegExp('^[0-9]{1,5}(\\.[0-9])?$');
```

Comment: @thomas: No operation - a command without any effect. Every token is matched exactly once by definition, unless stated otherwise. So `x` and `x{1}` are identical.

Answer (score 0):

Using literal notation would avoid to escape backslashes :

```
function validateLoad(load_value) {
    return /^\d{1,5}(\.\d)?$/.test(load_value)
}
```